# Custom mod rewrite (rewriting urls for WP multisite network) in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having this strange problem.
WP Multi Site Network has been created and pages that existed before were moved into it.
Everything works fine except, in old pages that was coded entirely in html, subsites were of format:

```
http://domain-a.com/subsite1.html
http://domain-b.com/subsite2.html
```

but now with WP pretty links they look this way:

```
http://domain-a.com/subsite1
http://domain-b.com/subsite2
```

Seo agency would like to make automagic rewrite of old links to new one. I have found sample  htpassword redirrect that looks this way:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*).html$ http://domain.com$1/
```

but it will not work correctly because there is domain name on right but none on the left.
I understand, that for each domain I should create different rule, because proppably it cant be done in one rule globally, but either case I dont know how to do it correctly.

In theory rewrite should take any address that is with .html at the end and rewrite it to exact same without .html at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your rule try this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*).html$ /$1/
```